# different IPs for same dns nameserver

Tags: dns, bind, nameservers

This is my configuration: I have 2 DNS servers with of course 2 different IPs and both of them have the nameserver `ns1.example.com`.

Now,I have to point a new domain to the new server but I have problems with it, if I dig `+trace` the domain it returns the old IP for `ns1.xxx.com` which is also existing.

Is it possible to have the following?

```
ns1.example.com 192.168.1.1

ns1.example.com 192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Whether it is suitable for your setup is impossible to tell with the above information.

Does DNS1 have the IP address 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1, is the subnet mask 255.255.0.0? Then yes, this is absolutely fine.

If DNS2's IP is 192.168.2.1 than no, I would change the configuration.